# Upgrading GeoServer 2.13 to 2.17 don't render all tiles

Tags: geoserver

I developed a simple application using GeoServer 2.13 previously and updated it to 2.17 and replace its data directory to the new one. The problem is after restarting the docker it does not load all tiles in some locations. The error specified in LayerPreview is `code="internalError" Rendering process failed` for those tiles. I didn't find any clue to this problem because those locations are rendered in higher zoom levels. The GeoServer logs stated nothing much but just the following lines:

```
2020-05-03 17:53:06,312 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web/wicket/bookmarkable/org.geoserver.web.admin.logpage, QueryString: 6-1.IFormSubmitListener-form&filter=false with /web/
2020-05-03 17:53:06,314 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-03 17:53:06,314 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-03 17:53:06,314 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-03 17:53:06,314 DEBUG [geoserver.ows] - Could not find a layer group named web
2020-05-03 17:53:06,315 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 140 locking in mode READ
2020-05-03 17:53:06,315 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 140 got the lock in mode READ
2020-05-03 17:53:06,315 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 140 locking in mode READ
2020-05-03 17:53:06,315 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 140 releasing the lock in mode READ
2020-05-03 17:53:06,317 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```